# Saving tweets in a file, but they are overwritten by Python

Tags: python, twitter

I am kind of new in programming. I have created a script that loops through a list of twitter ids, retrieves their timelines and saves them in a json archive. However, I think that each time it takes the last timeline and overwrites the file and keeps only the last one.

This is my code in the loop:

```
idfile = open('ids_part1.txt', 'r+')
for id in idfile:
    if id:
        id = id.strip()
        try:
            result = ret_timeline(user_id=id)
            if result:
                result_file = open('result1.json', 'w+')
                for st in result:
                    result_file.write(json.dumps(st._json, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
                result_file.close()
```

Can you please help me with that? Thank you very much!

Comment: `w+`, like `w`, **truncates** existing file content.

Comment: It is useful to read documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: You don't really need to keep opening the file. Just open it once before the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file in append mode, and you should be fine

```
result_file = open('result1.json', 'a')
```